# Using Regex in install4j Compiler Variable

Tags: install4j

During installation, install4J looks for a certain file format to load (and later extract). The file format is the following:

```
server_${compiler:component_name}_${compiler:modality_version}_${compiler:modality_os}_BN${compiler:timestamp}.tar.gz
```

Everything works except for the last compiler variable which is the timestamp. I would like that variable to be a regex:

```
([0-9]{4})(0[1-9]|1[0-2])(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])(2[0-3]|[01][0-9])([0-5][0-9])
```

However, install4j is unable to figure out that what I'm giving it is a regex and not hard-coded variable.

How can I resolve this?

Currently, I'm getting this during the build:

```
[INFO]       [WARNING] The path "..\..\target\resources\archives\server_merch_4.1_SP1_win-x86-64_BN([0-9]{4})(0[1-9]|1[0-2])(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])(2[0-3]|[01][0-9])([0-5][0-9]).tar.gz" does not exist.
```

If this is not possible, is there a way I can use the wildcard "*"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no ad-hoc regex pattern matching like that in install4j.

Use a "Set a variable" action where you list files yourself and write the matching file to an installer variable. In the action that reads the file you can then use the expression `${installer:myVariable}` where `myVariable` is the variable name configured in the "Set a variable" action.

Comment: Appreciate your help.Thank you.